# Stored Procedure runs in SQL Management Studio but not in Code

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am entering and updating data in two tables, creating queries with SP work in SQl server are OK, but to consult on a form in C # I generates an error.

Here are my table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[nationality](
    [nationalitycode] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nationality] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_nationality] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [nationalitycode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[user]   
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
    [code] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [lastname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [nationalitycode] [int] NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_user] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [code] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

When I run the following code to edit data I get:

> Sqlexception was unhandled Procedure or function 'sp_update' expects
>   parameter '@lastName', which was not supplied.

```
private void btnRec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", cn);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cn.Open();
   int fila = 0;
   switch (menup)
   {
      case menu.New:
         cmd.CommandText = "sp_insertdata";
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("code", 0);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txtName.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastName", txtlastName.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nationality", txtNationality.Text);
         cmd.Parameters["code"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
         fila = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         if (fila!=0)
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Good Registry" +      cmd.Parameters["code"].Value.ToString());
         }
         break;
```

Here is my edit code:

```
case menu.Edit:
   cmd.CommandText = "sp_update";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("code", txtCode.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", txtLastName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("nationality", txtNationality.Text);
    fila = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (fila!=0)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Update ok" +  cmd.Parameters["code"].Value.ToString());
    }
    break;
```

When I run the edit code I get:

> Sqlexception was unhandled Procedure or function 'sp_update' expects
>   parameter '@lastName', which was not supplied.

Here is the stored procedure definitions:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_insertdata]
@name nvarchar(50),
@lastname nvarchar(50),
@nationality nvarchar(50)
as
if  not exists(select * from nationality where nationality=@nationality)
begin
insert into nationality(nationality)values(@nationality)
end
declare @id int
select @id=nationalitycode from nationality where nationality=@nationality

insert into usuario(name,lastname,nationalitycode) values (@name,@lastname,@id)
```

/****************************************************************************************/

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_update]
@code int,
@name varchar(50),
@lastname varchar(50),
@nationality varchar(50)
as

if not exists (select * from nationality where nationality=@nationality)
begin
insert  into nationality(nationality)values(@nationality)
end

update user
SET  name= @name,lastname=@lastname,nationalitycode=(select nationalitycode from nationality where nationality=@nationality)
where code = @code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems in your insert stored proc and your insert code. The stored procedure does not have a parameter for code, but you are passing it as an input.  Your code should read:

```
case menu.New:
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_insertdata";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", txtlastName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationality", txtNationality.Text);
    cmd.Parameters["code"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    fila = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The Insert stored proc should include code as an output:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_insertdata]
   @name nvarchar(50),
   @lastname nvarchar(50),
   @nationality nvarchar(50),
   @code int output
as
   if  not exists(select * from nationality where nationality=@nationality)
   begin
    insert into nationality(nationality)values(@nationality)
   end
   declare @id int
   select @id=nationalitycode from nationality where nationality=@nationality

   insert into usuario(name,lastname,nationalitycode) values (@name,@lastname,@id)

   SET @code=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

For your update code, I would change to:

```
cmd.CommandText = "sp_update";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", txtCode.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txtLastName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationality", txtNationality.Text);
```

Comment: excellent response, now I have another little problem
to update the table on the form, only shown in the text fields.
the numbers recorded in the field code
I can I delete the code numbers and update records .. any idea to fix it?

Comment: @Andreu: Your follow up question looks to be beyond the scope of the original question--you may want to ask it as a separate question. (You may also want to rephrase as I have no clue what you're asking ;) Remember to mark the question as Accepted if it worked for you.